# how to use + as a character in c++ string

Tags: c++, string

I am creating a bool function to test the validity of an input string. One of the specs requires testing the placement of a + symbol. However, when I try and search for '+' within the string, nothing results. I am thinking this is because + is an operator? I have also tried using '+' and creating a substring at this location with no success.

simplified version of code:

```
bool isValidString(string s)
{
    size_t found1 = s.find_first_not of("123456789") //string should only contain numbers, B, and +
    if ( s[found1] == 'B' ) {
        found1++;
        if s[found1] == '+'
            return true;
        else
            return false; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping it using \? e.g '\+'

Comment: The `+` character doesn't have any special meaning *inside* of a string. So the root of your issue must be something else. We can't know unless you include a [mcve].

Comment: I have tried '\+' - sorry, that won't show as part of the original post?

Comment: Your 2nd `if` statement is missing `(` and `)`.

Comment: Your function has no return value if `s[found1] != 'B'`.

Comment: You are missing ';' at the end of the first assignment.

Comment: BTW, if your string is "B", you will be accessing out of bounds to check for the '+'.  You need to check the string length before you increment the index.

Answer (score 1):

If I may guess at your intent ...

Here are 3 ways to detect 'B+', in your strings, but the 3rd does not meet your requirements.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

// returns true when "B+" found in s
bool isValidString1 (std::string s)
{
   bool retVal = false;
   size_t found1 = s.find_first_not_of("123456789"); //string should only contain numbers, B, and +
   if ( s[found1] == 'B' )
   {
      found1++;
      retVal = (s[found1] == '+');
   }
   return retVal;
}

bool isValidString2  (std::string s)
{
   size_t found1 = s.find_first_not_of("123456789"); //string should only contain numbers, B, and +
   bool retVal = false;
   switch (s[found1])
   {
   case 'B': retVal = ('+' == s[found1+1]);      break;
   case '+': /* tbd - what do if out of order */ break;
   default : /* tbd - what do if not allowed  */ break;
   }
   return (retVal);
}

// simple, but does not reject the rest of non-digits 
bool isValidString3 (std::string s)
{
   size_t indx = s.find("B+");
   return (indx != std::string::npos);
}

void test(std::string s)
{
   std::cout << "\n  1  s: '" << s << "'  "
             << (isValidString1(s) ? "valid" : "invalid");

   std::cout << "\n  2  s: '" << s << "'  "
             << (isValidString2(s) ? "valid" : "invalid");

   std::cout << "\n  3  s: '" << s << "'  "
             << (isValidString3(s) ? "valid" : "invalid") << std::endl;
}

int main(int , char** )
{
   std::string s10 = "1234B+56789";
   test(s10);

   std::string s11 = "1234+B+5678";
   test(s11);

   std::string s12 = "B+12345678";
   test(s12);

   std::string s13 = "12345678B+";
   test(s13);

   std::string s14 = "12345678+B";
   test(s14);
}
```

Output looks like:

```
  1  s: '1234B+56789'  valid
  2  s: '1234B+56789'  valid
  3  s: '1234B+56789'  valid

  1  s: '1234+B+5678'  invalid
  2  s: '1234+B+5678'  invalid
  3  s: '1234+B+5678'  valid

  1  s: 'B+12345678'  valid
  2  s: 'B+12345678'  valid
  3  s: 'B+12345678'  valid

  1  s: '12345678B+'  valid
  2  s: '12345678B+'  valid
  3  s: '12345678B+'  valid

  1  s: '12345678+B'  invalid
  2  s: '12345678+B'  invalid
  3  s: '12345678+B'  invalid
```

---

It appears that the following (output from isValidStr3()) is actually not what you want.

```
  3  s: '1234+B+5678'  valid
```

---

I find no issue with '+', it is simply another char in a std::string.  No escaping needed.  In this context, it is not an operator.

Comment: None of the above "bool isValidStreamX(std::string s)" functions test for the string a) is digits, b) is not mulitple '+'s, c) is not multiple 'B's, etc.  I think the functions need a counter (or two?) to confirm the other issues.  You should plan more unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to work

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str{ "Smith, where Jones + + \"+ +\", \"+ +\" +."
        " \"+ +\" + + the examiners' approval." };
    string substr{ '+' };
    cout << "The string to be searched is:" << endl << str << endl;
    size_t offset{};
    size_t count{};
    size_t increment{ substr.length() };
    while (true)
    {
        offset = str.find(substr, offset);
        if (string::npos == offset)
            break;
        offset += increment;
        ++count;
    }
    cout << " The string \"" << substr
        << "\" was found " << count << " times in the string above."
        << endl;
    return 0;
}
```